# Find missing days in R Date sequence

Tags: r, time-series

let's say I have a series of dates in R, like so:

```
d <- as.Date(c('2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05'))
```

The date `2001-01-03` is missing. Is there a quick way to identify this? In reality I have a much longer series than just 4 observations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a range of dates based on the min and max dates in your vector and check with `%in%` which dates are missing.

```
d <- c('2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05')
d <- as.Date(d)
date_range <- seq(min(d), max(d), by = 1) 
date_range[!date_range %in% d] 
[1] "2001-01-03"
```